# Rails blog - is it a reasonable solution to store posts in partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to code up a blog using Rails and I'm trying to figure out the best approach to storing the posts themselves. I plan to use a lot of styling, formatting and images and that of course comes with a few challenges.

I've considered using a WYSIWYG HTML editor and storing the posts as HTML but I don't really like using them and I find them quite restrictive. Plus, editing the content poses problems and I'd like to work within my text editor.

I've considered using markdown, which would definitely make the storage element simpler, but I don't particularly want to have to write in markdown either.

I've absolutely no interest in storing it as XML and then parsing it for the display.

So the solution I came up with is to store the content of each post in a partial and have a database column called `content_partial` that references it. That way I can write them in the way I'm most comfortable with and I don't have to persist huge amounts of text/HTML/CSS etc. Of course it means potentially having a lot of partial files but that doesn't really bother me.

Is this a reasonable solution? Or are there any pitfalls that I haven't thought of? Alternative suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: "and have a database column called content_partial" - sooo, to write a new post you have to deploy? While common for static sites, this is really weird for a rails app.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't thought of that actually, that would be a bit of a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I'd like to work within my text editor

Nothing could be easier. Have your posts table have column `content` which will store html. Prepare the html in your local text editor. Copy-paste to a regular textarea in the post creation form. No WYSIWYG, nothing. Raw HTML. Then render content from the database.

Comment: I was under the impression that copying it back from the text area would remove all of the code formatting and require me putting it through a formatting tool but I just gave it a go and it turns out that was complete nonsense! I think if I have a 'post preview' page to work from so I don't have to update the post to see the changes then this now looks like the most inviting option. Thanks for the help Sergio

Comment: @DannySantos Glad you liked it. Don't forget to accept helpful answers :)

Comment: Right you are :)